# Remove the index, edit and show actions from my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I imagine this is fairly straight forward, but it's difficult to get the correct answer from google as delete/destroy an action is very similar to questions talking about the action: destroy()

I want to create a scaffold with just the **create** and **destroy** actions in my controller. I didn't use Nifty generator (which I think I will in the future).

My question is, what do I need to change in my application to fully remove the other actions? I'm talking about what changes in the routes file and other places, as well as the general files I'd need to delete such as views/modelname/show.erb

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume your model is a `User`

In routes.rb

`resources :users, only: [:new, :destroy]`

Delete everything other than `new.html.erb` from `app/views/users`

If you're going to use generators though it's probably quicker to do something like:

`rails g model User name:string username:string email:string`

`rails g controller Users new destroy`

Comment: Thanks, but this is still leaving me with routing errors

Comment: oops, I didn't mean to send that. I realise the errors aren't related to the question. I am trying to set the create action as the default and vie POST. I'm getting the error "No route matches [POST] "

Comment: p.s in my original question I meant Create and Destroy. Not New and Destroy.

Comment: Ok, switch to `resources :users, only: [:create, :destroy]` in your routes.rb file.

Comment: the problem is possibly here? <%= link_to 'Join Group', moderator_request_path(:group_id => @group.id), :method => :post %>

Comment: What's in your routes?  `resources :moderator_requests, only: [:create, :destroy]`?

Also you probably want `moderator_requests_path`

Comment: I have resources :moderator_requests, only: [:create, :destroy] and i'm trying 
  post "/moderator_requests" => "moderator_requests#create", :as => :moderator_requests_path

Comment: remove that line, it'll be handled by the resources

Comment: Thanks, I think my issue is that the url it still forming as a GET rather than POST?

Comment: Error: "destroy is defined by Active Record". I've set method to POST.. but it seems to be ignoring it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55771/discussion-between-baloo-and-david-sigley).